# How to Add Custom CSS and Script in AMP Pages

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amp-html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample document</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="AMPstyle.html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style amp-custom>
   @import "css/style1.css"; 
  {% include "css/style2.css" %}
    </style> 

<script type="application/ld+json" src="../Scripts/appjs/StaticCampaigns.js"></script>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "NewsArticle",
      "headline": "Article headline",
      "image": [
        "thumbnail1.jpg"
      ],
      "datePublished": "2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00"
    }
    </script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/initcarousel.css" /> -->

  </head>
  <body>
<h>AMP Pages Example.</h>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting invalid AMP Page when added CSS and script. i am not able to add stylesheet and CSS not working. Custom CSS and Script is not working. please suggest how can i add custom CSS (@import "css/style1.css";) and Script(src="../Scripts/appjs/StaticCampaigns.js") in AMP pages.

Answer (score 2):

AMP documents require all CSS to be inline in the page head and require you to use the `amp-custom` property on the style tag. It looks like you're attempting to add an `@import` statement in the page head which wouldn't be valid even if this wasn't AMP. I'd suggest compiling it first and then copying the contents into the style tags. Keep in mind there's `50,000` byte [size limit](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/spec#cust) too.

For example:

```
<style amp-custom>
  h1 {
   color: red
  }
</style>
```

As for the script, you're not able to include authored JavaScript in AMP documents. You'll need to look for an equivalent [AMP component](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components).

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me, try this

```
<style amp-custom>
        @import url('css/main.css');
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).