# How do I apply custom css styles only to Amp pages

Tags: css, wordpress, amp-html

I have a wordpress website which I am coverting to an AMP website for now I am using the [amp plugin](http://amp.dev/)
Now my website has a lot of css files and the style that I can inline is limited so I am trying to add a custom css using :

```
<style amp-custom>
 .someclass={/*my custom css I want it to affect only amp pages*/}

</style>
```

I can add the style without problem to all pages by adding it to the header.php file, Now The thing is I want this tyle to be applied only to my amp pages , they have a special urls (Adding ?amp at the end).

- www.mywebsite.com : is my website
- www.mywebsite.com?amp is the amp page for my website, I am overriding the css by adding these inline custom css to affect these pages.

**can I make it so that the custom css is only applied to the amp pages ?**

Comment: Don't the amp pages have some additional styleclass in the body, which you could then use to create a specific css rule on?

Comment: basically I am using some transitional plugin so I have 2 websites , one of them is an Amp website with Urls finishing with ?amp and I want the styling to target only the Amp pages @Sami Ahmed Siddiqui did answer the question. But I don't have the style everytime. maybe I have 2 <style custom-amp> tags

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to suggest a non-js solution

Comment: Thx Steven De Groote  You are always welcome to suggest a better answer for this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add Custom CSS and Script in AMP Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444224/how-to-add-custom-css-and-script-in-amp-pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `amp_post_template_css` action if you are using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) plugin.

```
function custom_post_template_css() {
  ?>
  .someclass={
    /*my custom css I want it to affect only amp pages*/
  }
  <?php
}
add_action( 'amp_post_template_css','custom_post_template_css', 11 );
```

Please refer to the [Custom CSS](https://amp-wp.org/documentation/how-the-plugin-works/classic-templates/) for the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply and for the links,so this plugin is not so good when you choose transitional for non native amp themes, better choose reader mode for those ones

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky but After I searched in the forums I found out that the amp plugins [provides a method is_amp_endpoint()](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/check-if-on-amp-page/) for knowing if the page is an Amp page so with a little PHP in the Wordpress theme header.file we can affect all the AMP pages .

```
<style amp-custom>
<?php
    if (is_amp_endpoint()){
        echo(".mypanel_class{color:white !important;}");
        echo("div#myid{display:none;}");
    }
    ?>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the proposed solutions didn't work for me, I tried the one below and it works:

```
add_action( 'amp_post_template_css', function ( $amp_template ) {
    ?>
    .some-class {
        color: blue; /*Use Normal CSS Here! */
    }
    <?php
} );
```